# Puppeteer captha failure

Tags: javascript, browser, automation, bots, puppeteer

[error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Em3ru.png)

I start my browser like this:

```
browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false,
      executablePath: "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe",
      ignoreDefaultArgs: true,
      ignoreDefaultArgs: [
        "--allow-pre-commit-input",
        "--disable-background-networking",
        "--disable-background-timer-throttling",
        "--disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows",
        "--disable-breakpad",
        "--disable-client-side-phishing-detection",
        "--disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages",
        "--disable-component-update",
        "--disable-default-apps",
        "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
        "--disable-extensions",
        "--disable-features=Translate,BackForwardCache,AcceptCHFrame,MediaRouter,OptimizationHints",
        "--disable-hang-monitor",
        "--disable-ipc-flooding-protection",
        "--disable-popup-blocking",
        "--disable-prompt-on-repost",
        "--disable-renderer-backgrounding",
        "--disable-sync",
        "--enable-automation",
        "--enable-blink-features=IdleDetection",
        "--enable-features=NetworkServiceInProcess2",
        "--export-tagged-pdf",
        "--force-color-profile=srgb",
        "--metrics-recording-only",
        "--no-first-run",
        "--password-store=basic",
        "--use-mock-keychain",
        "--remote-debugging-port=0",
      ],
      args: [
        "--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data",
        "--flag-switches-begin",
        "--remote-debugging-port=9222",
        "--enable-features=GlobalMediaControlsCastStartStop",
        "--flag-switches-end",
      ],
    });
```

I noticed that if you go to the site with captcha in the browser that opens, then everything works, but if you do it with

```
page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto("https://...");
```

Then the captcha pops up. This was not the case 3-4 days ago, perhaps the cloudflare captcha has been updated. Help me find a solution to the problem please

I tried to put different arguments to launch the browser and came to the conclusion that nothing works and most likely this is not due to the arguments to launch the browser, but some kind of joke with opening a new tab using a script. I also tried setting the user agent, it used to help, but literally 4 days ago the captcha stopped working even with the user agent